# Webpage is not loading in VBA macro Excel

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have written a code in VBA macro Excel. I am trying to search a request id on a website and then filter the data by using two dates (starting and ending).

After searching for the ID the website is loading properly but as soon as the code is entering the dates and clicking on the filter button the website doesn't load completely. It directly takes another ID from excel sheet and enter it in the search box without waiting for the website load for the date filter applied.

Below is the code:

```
Sub reconwebscrap() ' ' reconwebscrap Macro ' ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+R '

    Dim requestsearchrange As Range
    Dim cell1 As Range
    Dim cell2 As Range
    Dim entire As Range
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim revocdate As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tags As Object
    Dim tagx As Object
    Dim tags2 As Object
    Dim tagsx As Object
    Dim tag3 As Object
    Dim tag3x As Object
    Dim revocdate2 As String

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

    i = 0

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FalseRevokes")
        Set requestsearchrange = .Range(.Range("B2"), .Range("B2").End(xlDown))
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Request Check"

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Request Check")
        Set entire = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
    End With
the_start:

    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    'Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'These attributes decide the position of internet explorer window.
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    IE.Top = 0
    IE.Left = 0
    IE.Width = 800
    IE.Height = 600

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Disable the viewing of Internet Explorer window.
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    IE.Visible = True

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Navigate to the website.
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    IE.navigate ("https://ibid.abc.com/RMT/QuickSearch")

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Let the website load completely.
    'Error handling in case the website is not available.
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Do Until Not IE.Busy
        DoEvents
        Application.StatusBar = " Running"
    Loop

    'Do
        'DoEvents
            'If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                'IE.Quit
                'Set IE = Nothing
                'GoTo the_start:
            'End If
    'Loop Until IE.readystate = 4

    MsgBox "webpage has loaded"

    revocdate = InputBox("Enter the request submission date")
    revocdate2 = InputBox("Enter the Request Submission date limit")

    'Set tags = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("img")

    Set tag3 = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    For Each cell1 In requestsearchrange
        IE.document.getElementById("dashboardSelect").Value = "recipientSid"
        IE.document.getElementById("quickSearchCriteriaVar").Value = cell1.Value

        Set tags = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("img")

        For Each tagx In tags
            If tagx.alt = "Search Request" Then
                tagx.Click
            End If
        Next tagx

        Do Until Not IE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set tags2 = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

        For Each tagsx In tags2
            If tagsx.ID = "startDtsubmittedDate" Then
                tagsx.Value = revocdate
            End If
        Next tagsx
        For Each tagsx In tags2
            If tagsx.ID = "endDtsubmittedDate" Then
                tagsx.Value = revocdate2
            End If
        Next tagsx
        For Each tagsx In tags2
            If tagsx.ID = "filterBtn" Then
                tagsx.Click
                'Do Until Not IE.Busy
                    'DoEvents
                'Loop
            End If
        Next tagsx
        'IE.document.getElementById("startDtsubmittedDate").Value = revocdate
        'IE.document.getElementById("endDtsubmittedDate").Value = revocdate2
        'IE.document.getElementById("filterBtn").Click

        Do Until Not IE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        i = i + 1
        Application.StatusBar = i & " Running"


    Next cell1

    Application.StatusBar = ""

    'For Each cell1 In requestsearchrange

        'With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            '"URL;https://ibid.abc.com/RMT/SearchRequest.action?searchField=recipientSid&quickSearchCriteria =" & cell1.Value & "&listObjName=request&viewAll=&noOfRecords=" _
            ', Destination:=Range("$A$1").End(xlDown))
            '.Name = _
            '"SearchRequest.action?searchField=recipientSid&quickSearchCriteria=V650460&listObjName=request&viewAll=&noOfRecords="
            '.FieldNames = True
            '.RowNumbers = False
            '.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            '.PreserveFormatting = True
            '.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            '.BackgroundQuery = True
            '.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            '.SavePassword = False
            '.SaveData = True
            '.AdjustColumnWidth = True
            '.RefreshPeriod = 0
            '.WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
            '.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            '.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            '.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            '.WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            '.WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            '.WebDisableRedirections = False
            '.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        'End With



        'For Each cell2 In entire
            'If cell2.Value <> "Completed" Or cell2.Value = "Cancelled" Or cell2.Value = "Rejected" Or cell2.Value = "Reopened" Or cell2.Value = "In Progress" Then
                'cell2.Rows.Delete
            'End If
        'Next cell2
    'ActiveCell.Rows("1:62").EntireRow.Select
    'Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    'ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Range("A1").Select
    'Next cell1
End Sub
```

I am trying to click on the filter in the below code and then wait for it to load but it is not working.

```
For Each tagsx In tags2
    If tagsx.ID = "filterBtn" Then
        tagsx.Click
        Do Until Not IE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End If
Next tagsx
```

Comment: In the complete code, the loop used for loading the IE is in comments, but I have used it and it is not working.

Comment: I noticed that after clicking on the filter button the website URL Changes. I tried using

Do While IE.LocationURL = "https://ibid.abc.com/RMT/SearchRequest.action?searchField=recipientSid&quickSearchCriteria=" & cell1.Value & "&listObjName=request&viewAll=&noOfRecords="
                     Sleep 3000
Loop

But it is also not working. Actually it is not clicking on the filter button I guess.

Comment: Below is the HTML code for the button:

<DIV onclick="filterColumn('outstandingReqTable', '', 'outStanding');" id=filterBtn title="Filter Data" class=btnBlue style="WIDTH: 60px">Filter</DIV>